# Is it possible to make a unique tree in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tree

```
using TreeEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class TreeSeeder : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        Tree tree = GetComponent<Tree>();
        TreeData treeData = Instantiate(tree.data as TreeData);
        TreeGroupRoot root = treeData.root;
        root.seed = Random.Range(0, 9999999);
        tree.data = treeData;
        treeData.UpdateMesh(tree.transform.worldToLocalMatrix, out var outMaterials);
        MeshFilter meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        meshFilter.mesh = treeData.mesh;
        meshFilter.mesh.ToString(); // i don't know why this is necessary, but it is
    }
}
```

It doesn't function if I don't enter the ToString. I have never seen something so fascinating in my life as this. What's the issue? Are you familiar with this?

I have tried `UpdateSeed()`. it didn't work.

Comment: `meshFilter.mesh.ToString();` doesn't make any sense .. it should even throw warnings as you don't assign the returned string to anything .. this will only return the name of the according `Mesh` .. what exactly does `doesn't function` mean? and btw usually the `treeData.mesh` already is the same as the `meshFilter.mesh`, right?

Comment: you can call functions with no assignment. there will be a warning in editor, not in runtime. what I asked is it not work when I dont call the toString function.